# Change interface IP and restart the interface without dropping ssh connection

Tags: centos, ssh, networking

I am creating a post OS install configuration script. After installation, machine reinstalled has a default static IP I can connect to when the machine boots. I would like to be able to execute a script on the machine over `ssh` that changes the default static IP of the interface I am connected to the machine over. Once I change the IP in */etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-<interface>* script, I run `ifdown <interface> && ifup <interface>` for the changes to take effect, however, this drops my ssh connection as the IP on the interface is now different (`ifdown && ifup` seems to not drop ssh connection if the IP of the remote machine remains the same). Is there a way to not lose the ssh connection when restarting the interface and changing IP?

Comment: The established ssh (TCP) connection will continue to send packets addressed to the IP address your machine had at the start of the connection.  You're saying your machine will no longer have that IP address, so even if the ifdown/ifup didn't disconnect the session, your machine's TCP/IP stack will reject the packets to the old address and the ssh session will hang and then timeout anyway.

Answer (score 1):

SSH is built on top of TCP/IP. This is a stateful protocol that connects between {IP address_client, port_client} on one end and {IP address_server, port_server} on the other. You need all four values for the connection to remain established.

(A NAT gateway transparently changes one or more of these values for a connection, remembering the original values for substitution into returning traffic.)

You're asking if it's possible to change the IP address. This is one of the four necessary values, so if you do this the connection cannot remain active.

In terms of your requirement you could avoid resetting the IP address until a system restart, but instead add a transient additional IP address to allow new connections on the new IP address while keeping the original IP address in place for your control channel.

```
ip addr add 10.10.10.10/24 dev ens99
```

Thinking further, if you're doing this interactively you could possibly use `screen` to insulate the shell session from the ssh transport.

Comment: I liked your transient IP idea so that's what I tried to implement it with a twist. I connected over the default static IP and created a transient IP with `ip add add IP dev DEV valid_lft 120`. I thought that this would allow me to connect via the transient IP, and change the default static IP, and then `ifdown && ifup` the interface without losing connection as now I am connected over the transient IP. `ifdown`, however, removes the transient IP address (before *valid_lft* is over), and I lose the connection. I'll probably just end up modifying configs and rebooting, which I wanted to avoid..

Comment: Why do you want to `ifdown`/`ifup` at all? Leave the transient in place. Next time the system reboots it'll sort itself out